# Apache virtual host to tomcat server

Tags: apache, tomcat, virtualhost

I would like to set apache to root to my tomcat server in the same machine.Apache is listening to port 80 and tomcat to 9090. The dns name of my service is example.com.gr the machine ip is something like "150.111.111.11" and in the httpd file i wrote this

```
   NameVirtualHost *:80

   <VirtualHost *:80>
   <ServerName example.com.gr
   ErrorLog logs/example.com.gr.gr_error_log
   TransferLog logs/example.com.gr.gr_access_log

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://150.111.111.11:9090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://150.111.111.11:9090/

    <Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Location>

    </VirtualHost>
```

But when i hit example.com.gr i get  (110) Connection timed out,but if i hit example.com.gr:9090 i see my portal.Any ideas?

Comment: ` /../../apache2/bin/httpd -S` What is the status u get in this ?

Comment: [Reference](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/apache-virtual-host/)

Comment: Thank you for response unlucky but i didn't understand very well what did you mean with  /../../apache2/bin/httpd -S

Comment: its the path to httpd file to check status of the virtual hosts configuration

Comment: Finally the configuration is correct the problem was that firewall didn't let apache listen to 80